# PostgreSQL - select data from stored procedure

Tags: postgresql-11

I working with creating new SP which will insert or do a select and return ID of the founded/inserted record.  Parameter ID is inout parameter of stored procedure.

I was helped with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476508/invoke-stored-procedure-and-return-id

I have prepared table , stored procedure and select statement:
https://dbfiddle.uk/XHPxeW_b

but getting error, i  nearly come to end of the internet and did not found a proper solution. Error:

```
     do $$
  declare _id int;
    Begin
    call InsertSelectCategory('Add-Hoc', _id);
    select _id
    end; 
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
    ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
    HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your INSERT could be made more efficient (and safe for concurrent inserts), by defining a unique constraint on `name` and using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. Also: you don't need to make `id` unique if it's already the the primary key.  https://dbfiddle.uk/a5dTqxN6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just put a "SELECT" into a procedure and expect the output to show up "somewhere". If you want to print something, use [RAISE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) inside your `DO` block:

```
do $$
declare 
  _id int;
begin
  call InsertSelectCategory('Add-Hoc', _id);
  raise notice 'New ID: %', _id;  
end; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

However, procedures aren't meant to return results, using a function is a better choice.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function InsertSelectCategory( _name varchar) 
  returns integer
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $procedure$
with vals as (
  select _name as name
)
insert into Category (name)
select v.name
from vals as v
where not exists (select * from Category as c where c.name = v.name)
returning id;
$procedure$
;
```

Then use it like this:

```
do $$
declare 
  _id int;
begin
  _id := InsertSelectCategory('Add-Hoc');
  raise notice 'New ID: %', _id;
end; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```